# problems amd inverted index and frequency

Tags: cpu-word, doc, inverted-index

An inverted index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) is a data structure that aims to allow a full-text search. From a series of documents containing text, the inverted index contains the different words indicating in which documents they appear and how often. The process of generating the inverted index from the set of documents is called indexing.

Given the documents:

{d1: "I saw the cat on the mat",
  d2: "I saw the dog on the mat",
  d3: "I saw the cat and the rat sat on the mat"}

generate by MapReduce an inverted index that has the following structure:

{‘W1’: [(docId1, numOccu1),…, (docIdN, numOccuN)],
    ‘W2’: […],…}
where w are the different words that appear (I, saw, ...), docId are the document identifiers (docId1, docId2, ...) and numOccu are the number of times the word appears in the document.

You are asked to write the map functions in pseudocode and reduce and describe the results of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

If we index by (text, word within the text), the index with location in text is:

```html
 I               (1, 1); (2,1); (3,1)
 saw             (1, 2); (2,2); (3,2)
 the             (1, 3); (1, 6); (2,3); (2,6); (3,3); (3,6); (3,10)
 cat             (1, 4); (3,4)
 on              (1, 5); (2,5); (3,9)
 mat             (1, 7); (2,7); (3,11)
 dog (2,4) 
 and  (3,5)
 rat (3,7)
 sat (3,8)
```

The word “I” is in document 1 (“I saw the cat on the mat”) starting at word 1, so has an entry (1, 1) and word “cat” is in document 1 and 3 at ‘4th’ position respectively (here position is based on word). The index may have weights, frequencies, or other indicators.